# How to resolve could not identify current directory: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs

I would run postgreSQl but when I start `pg_start` I got this error

```
`could not identify current directory: Permission denied
 could not identify current directory: Permission denied
 could not identify current directory: Permission denied
 The program "postgres" is needed by pg_ctl but was not found in the
 same directory as "pg_ctl".
 Check your installation.`
```

I tried many ways like `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start` , `brew services restart postgresql` , `brew search "postgresql".` ,and I use `brew install --cask navicat-for-postgresql` one time for up-date Homebrew but still I get error.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue after upgrading my postgres.

```
brew upgrade postgresql@14
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I recebe `No available formula with the name "postgresql".`

Comment: They changed it to `@` and `version` for example, `brew upgrade postgresql@14`